# Convert Matlab to R gives non-conformable arrays

Tags: r, matlab

I need to port a Matlab script to R.

Here's a snippet:

```
n = 3;
M = 7;
tau = 1;
shift_mat_ind = reshape(0:tau:(n-1)*tau,[],1) * ones(1,M-(n-1)*tau) +...
    ones(n, 1) * reshape(1:(M-(n-1)*tau),1,[]);
```

I tried to translate this to R with:

```
n = 3;
M = 7;
tau = 1;
helperTerm1 = seq(0, (n-1)*tau, tau);
helperTerm2 = 1:(M-(n-1)*tau);
shift_mat_ind = matrix(helperTerm1,length(helperTerm1),1) %*% matrix(1,1,M-(n-1)*tau) + 1 %*% matrix(helperTerm2,1,length(helperTerm2));
```

My Matlab knowledge is very limited, so I don't know what went wrong here.

The error message is:

```
Error in matrix(helperTerm1, length(helperTerm1), 1) %*% matrix(1, 1,  : 
non-conformable arrays
```

Which parts did I get wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix(helperTerm1,length(helperTerm1),1) %*% 
matrix(1,1,M-(n-1)*tau)
```

gives a 3x5 matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

and the rest

```
1 %*% matrix(helperTerm2,1,length(helperTerm2))
```

gives a 1x5 matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

You should add matrices with the same dimensions.